# Azure Function - Host Json file is missing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-app

I am using Terraform to deploy Azure Functions infrastructure through Azure DevOps release pipeline. Everything works fine but starting from last Friday, I got an error said Function runtime is unable to start. After some investigation, I found out the host.json file is not generated in the Azure Function. Any ideas on what's the potential fix for this?
(Only change is updated Function version v2 to v3, but even I downgrade back to v2, same problem still exists).

[image]

Environment:
Azure Function V2/V3
Resources Created By Terraform using App Service Plan Tier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is an internal issue. [Rising a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) from the Azure portal will be a good way to find its reason.

Comment: Found out it is related to the terraform upgrade to 0.12.19.